# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Todo''

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

This is my code and it says +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Todo''. I have no clue how to fix it.

```
(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController

{
        if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

// Set up the fetched results controller.
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Todo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];



// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Self.managedobjectcontext is nil so figure out why and fix that

Comment: I thought he had trouble interpreting the meaning of the error message and did not realise the moc he was using has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set up your managed object context. So, above where you make your request, do something like

```
// Set up our RestKit stores
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
self.managedObjectContext = [managedObjectStore persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

So my entire request method looks like

```
- (void)loadPosts
{
// Set up our RestKit stores
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
self.managedObjectContext = [managedObjectStore persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// Make a RestKit request
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/posts/"
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@ %@", operation, mappingResult);
                                              [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                          }];

}
```